# Changes not loading even after hard refresh

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose

Got a very weird issue, so I'm using Docker containers to de-couple a new app.

Container 1 = Laravel
Container 2 = React

My containers spin up with no issues, I've CLI'd onto the React container and ran `npx create-react-app ./` which has created a new app.

I've then ran `npm start` and the standard React page loads up.

Now when I make any changes to any files the changes don't get refreshed in the browser.  To be clear I'm not talking about hot reloading, if I manually hit the refresh button the changes still do not show.  I've ran in incognito mode to ensure it's not a local cache issue which hasn't solved it.  I've also checked the files in the container and the files themselves update.  If I stop NPM and then start it again and then refresh the browser the changes then show.

How can I get this to work without the need to `npm start` on every change?